# Command Line only UNIX/Linux OS

Tags: linux, command-line, lightweight

Does anybody know of any lightweight Linux/UNIX [command-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) only distros? I'm trying to look for one that's less than 80MB if possible and comes with the minimum amount of required software included in the box. Any Linux/UNIX distros that can fit this would be greatly appreciated! If there aren't any that can fit this then what are the alternatives that I can use instead?

Thanks!

Comment: As with all distro recommendations, the best solution is for you to try them and see. Below 80 MB is going to be troublesome though since a fairly vanilla Linux kernel is roughly 71 MiB anyhow.

Comment: I want a pony...

Comment: similar [closed question](http://superuser.com/q/265398), Also [this](http://superuser.com/q/275540) may helpful

Comment: look at [tinycore](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/). then get @jasonwryan a pony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Install ["Ubuntu command-line system"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems#Install_an_Ubuntu_command-line_system) and try [**Minimal CD**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

> The command-line version of Ubuntu is a sparse system without any graphical elements. It's a text-only version of what lies underneath all the advanced graphical elements. It's also the starting point for a minimal installation.

You can download following Ubuntu 32 or 64 bit minimal ISO images:

- [32-bit PC (x86)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A32-bit_PC_.28x86.29)
- [64-bit PC (amd64, x86_64)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A64-bit_PC_.28amd64.2C_x86_64.29)
- [32-bit PowerPC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A32-bit_PowerPC.2A.2A)
- [64-bit PowerPC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A64-bit_PowerPC.2A.2A)

They are all smaller than 80 MB.

For more Information, Visit : [**this**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems).

Comment: Also take look at [Ubuntu server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download)

Comment: Thise minimal image are network install images. They download the OSnat at install time

Answer (score 3):

I guess almost all Distros have a minimal version without GUI. Dont know any below 80MB, but I suggest the [CentOS minimal](http://mirror.nbrc.ac.in/centos/6.5/isos/x86_64/), which is around 400MB.

But there are distros below 80MB but they include both GUI and CLI. So I guess if 80MB is your limit you can use them and simply not use the GUI.

1. [Slitaz](http://www.slitaz.org/en/get/) is just cool.
2. [Damn Small Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/damnsmall/dslcore/) (DSL) lol :D just 10MB.